# How do I mock an HTTPResponse with image data in tornado?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tornado

### Problem

I am testing a handler for a `tornado` web application. This is my test case:

```
class HandlerTestCase(tornado_openapi3.AsyncOpenAPITestCase):

    def get_app(self) -> Application:
        return make_some_app()

    @mock.patch.object(Client, 'get')
    def test_some_handler(self, mock_get):
        mock_get.return_value = HTTPResponse(request=HTTPRequest(url='some_url'), code=200,
                                             buffer=io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(b'test_buffer')),
                                             headers=HTTPHeaders({'Content-Type': 'image/*'}))
        response = self.fetch(<some_path>, raise_error=False)
        self.assertEquals(response.code, 200)
```

Even though I explicitly set the response's `mimetype` to `image/*`, I get the following error message:

```
openapi_core.templating.media_types.exceptions.MediaTypeNotFound: Content for the following mimetype not found: application/json. Valid mimetypes: ['image/*']
```

The valid mimetypes are specified in my OpenAPI schema specifications, but I don't understand why the response's mimetype seems to be `application/json`.

### Solution

The response headers were not written into the response in my tested code. I adapted that. This is a good example of test-driven development, I guess.

Comment: What's the output of `print(mock_get.return_value.headers['Content-Type'])`?